# JAVASCRIPT ARRAY (map and reduce)

Tags: javascript, json, array

Como vai pessoal

Eu tenho cá este array:

```
[
  {dia:2,turno: turno1,M:1,T:0,N:0},
  {dia:2,turno: turno2,M:0,T:2,N:0},
  {dia:2,turno: turno3,M:0,T:0,N:1},
    
  {dia:3,turno: turno1,M:122,T:0,N:0},
  {dia:3,turno: turno2,M:0,T:21,N:0},
  {dia:3,turno: turno3,M:0,T:0,N:12}
]
```

eu quero transformar ele para esse array aqui!!

```
[
    {dia:2,turno1:1,turno2:2,turno3:1},
    {dia:3,turno1:122,turno2:21,turno3:12},
]
```

Tendo em conta que:
No

> dia 2 no **turno 1** ele soma todos os valores de **M**
>
> dia 2 no **turno 2** ele soma todos os valores de **T**
>
> dia 2 no **turno 3** ele soma todos os valores de **N**
>
> **O mesmo acontece no dia 3**

Comment: Nos exemplos o valor a somar está sempre isolado, sendo os restantes zero. É sempre dessa forma ou existem exceções ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas dá para fazer assim:

```js
array = [{dia:2,turno: 'turno1',M:1,T:0,N:0},  {dia:2,turno: 'turno2',M:0,T:2,N:0},  {dia:2,turno: 'turno3',M:0,T:0,N:1},  {dia:3,turno: 'turno1',M:122,T:0,N:0},  {dia:3,turno: 'turno2',M:0,T:21,N:0},  {dia:3,turno: 'turno3',M:0,T:0,N:12}]

resultado = []
array.map(function(a) {
     resultado[a['dia']] = resultado[a['dia']] || {dia: a['dia']}
     resultado[a['dia']][a['turno']] = (a['M'] + a['T'] + a['N'])
})

console.log(resultado.filter(String))
```

Acredito que não há muito o que explicar. O `map()` irá executar a função para cada item da array, que irá popular o `resultado`, se baseando no dia do item atual, então somará todos os `M`, `T`, `N` para tal turno.

Comment: Obrigado por ter respondido @Inkeliz, mas olha nao percebi o porque do `console.log(resultado.filter(String))`

Comment: @DaltonHarvey O `filter` é para cortar alguns resultados, no caso os que ficam como `undefined`.

Comment: @Isac thanks pela explicacao... entendido agora